# How to toggle introspection in graphql (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I need to toggle introspection in apollo-graphql nodejs server. It means that user has to have ability to turn on and turn off introspection when he wants it.
I found two ways to do it:

1. During graphql instance creation [link](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/security/why-you-should-disable-graphql-introspection-in-production/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20turn%20off%20introspection,on%20your%20Apollo%20Server%20instance.)
2. Or via middleware which filter out all "__schema"  and "__types" requests - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-disable-introspection)

Is there anything else? I don't want to restart server after each toggle or use dirty tricks as middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Apollo tools.
But can suggest to migrate to [GraphQL-Yoga](https://www.graphql-yoga.com/) and add the [useDisableIntrospection](https://www.envelop.dev/plugins/use-disable-introspection) plugin, which has conditional toggle flag

Comment: migration to another graphql server is impossible in my case.